# How to get help on a class' method

Tags: matlab

How do you get help for a class method/function when there are other functions of the same name?

For example, the `predict` method/function works for both [TreeBagger](http://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/treebagger-class.html) and [GeneralizedLinearModel](http://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/generalized-linear-regression-1.html) class.

How do I get the respective helpfiles for these functions using `doc`, as currently `doc predict` returns the help for the `CompactClassificationTree` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/treebagger.predict.html

http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/generalizedlinearmodel.predict.html

`predict` is a method of each class. You can also call it like `myTreeBagger.predict(data)`

Comment: thanks, sorry, I have added a clarification to my question. I want to be able to call these helpfiles using the `doc` command.

Comment: `doc TreeBagger.predict`